# NULL value with firestore IN query

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I want to craft a query that returns all documents with no value, either `null` or `''`.

I have a table with three documents, each having a field `a`
[image]

When performing an IN query, the document with the value `null` is not returned. Is this the expected behavior? How can I also include `null`?

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and [Formatting text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this the expected behavior?

Yes, that's expected behavior. Why? It's simply because when passing a list, that list should be of a type of object. An empty string is an object, however, a `null` it's **not** an object. So you cannot expect to return documents where `a` holds the value of `null` when using the `in` operator. A workaround would be to use an [OR query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#limits_on_or_queries), or alternatively to use a simple where call:

```
.where("a", "==", null)
```

Together with another where call using an `in` operator, but without adding `null` inside the list.

Comment: I see. However in js `typeof null === 'object'`, can you point me to the documentation, where it expects an object?

Comment: `null` in theory should represent "nothing". It is supposed to be something that doesn't exist. In other words, something that isn't yet an instance. Unfortunately, in JavaScript, the data type of `null` is an object. However, in other many programming languages, it doesn't. `null` is **not** an object, hence that behavior. So this is happening because Firebase should behave the same on all platforms. So it's more about consistency. Firestore should return the same results no matter what platform you're using.